# jQuery - how to select a cell AND its previous sibling

Tags: jquery, clone, siblings

I have the following table structure.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I need to do clone all the cells with a class of "selectable", AND it's immediate previous sibling, and insert the clones in a new row. In other words, i need the result to be:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
        <td>ASDF</td>
        <td class="selectable">ASDF</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can successfully clone the cells with a class of "selectable" by using the following. (I know this isn't valid markup as the 'TR' tags are missing. Just trying to shorten my example as much as possible.)

```
$('tr').each(function(){
    $(this).after($(this).find('td.selectable').clone());
})
```

However, I cannot work out how to include the previous sibling in the clone as well.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the previous sibling, and then [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/) to merge the two together. To insert the new row, just create it, and append the merged collection to it by using [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$(this).after( $('<tr>').append( $(this).find('td.selectable').prev().addBack().clone() ) );
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBnqP/8/)

Comment: addBack? I have never heard of that.  Every day is a school day! Of course it works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.